# Physics Simulation Ball falling into floor

Tags: c#, physics, monogame

I have been making a physics simulation of a ball for the past couple of days with MonoGame and C#. The ball bounces with gravity fine, but when the bouncing of the ball gets too low, the ball just goes into the floor. Is there any way I can stop this from happening?
I have already tried lowering the gravity constant, changing how the collision works, etc. but nothing seems to work.
(I am fairly new to working with graphics so a simple explanation would be most helpful)

```cs
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Particle_Simulation
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Texture2D particleTexture;

        SpriteFont font;

        Rectangle particle;

        Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(4, 0);
        Vector2 acceleration = new Vector2(0, 0.25f);

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            //graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width;
            //graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height;
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }
        
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            //Load your game content here
            particleTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ball");
            font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("textFont");
            particle = new Rectangle(200, 200, 60, 60);
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            //Add your update logic here
            velocity.X += acceleration.X;
            velocity.Y += acceleration.Y;
            
            particle.X += (int)velocity.X;
            particle.Y += (int)velocity.Y;

            if (particle.Top <= 0 || particle.Bottom >= GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height)
                velocity.Y = -velocity.Y;
            if (particle.Left <= 0 || particle.Right >= GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width)
                velocity.X = -velocity.X;

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            //Add your drawing code here
            spriteBatch.Begin();

            spriteBatch.Draw(particleTexture, particle, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "X: " + velocity.X.ToString() + " Y: " + velocity.Y.ToString(), new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);

            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is insufficient information in your post to know _exactly_ why the collision doesn't prevent the object from passing through the floor plane. However, the several different possibilities are well-described in the duplicate posts. If you still have trouble after reviewing those, post a new question in which you provide a good [mcve] and a more detailed explanation of the problem, what you've tried so far to fix it, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have looked at those other questions, but they seem to be dealing with pre-built collision items in Unity. The difference between those and this question is that I am creating my own collision detection and not using Unity's built in collision.

Comment: _"I am creating my own collision detection and not using Unity's built in collision"_ -- well, the first thing to change then is, don't do that. You're using a platform with a fine physics engine and collision detection system. It will work at least as well as anything you're going to implement. Alternatively, do the same thing Unity3d does and use the fixed update for your physics (which is actually explained in at least one of those duplicates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those classic problems with collision detection, where the collision occurs at some point along the object's path but the object moves far enough that the next tick doesn't fix the problem, leaving the object - your ball in this case - to fall forever outside of the viewport.

To solve this you need to not only change the vertical velocity but also have the ball reflect off the collision point. You're already bouncing the velocity vector, you just need to add position reflection. The simple way is to just take the amount of overshoot and subtract it from the limit, putting the ball back in bounds:

```
if (particle.Top < 0)
{
    velocity.Y = -velocity.Y;
    particle.Y = -particle.Y;
}
else if (particle.Bottom >= GraphicsDevice.ViewPort.Height)
{
    velocity.Y = -velocity.Y;
    particle.Y = GraphicsDevice.ViewPort.Height - (particle.Bottom - GraphicsDevice.ViewPort.Height + particle.Height);
}
```

Do the same for the `X` portions of velocity and position. In most cases the end result should be fine even for corner penetration.

Since you're just reflecting the whole velocity you'll get some accumulating errors that will result in the ball bouncing 'higher' after each impact. Imagine a ball dropping straight down but currently just above the surface. After acceleration the ball's velocity is (roughly) correct when there is no collision. But... if the collision occurs at 10% of the travel distance then only a portion of the acceleration would be added to the velocity up to that point, then the rest of the path would be slowed because the vertical velocity is now opposed to the acceleration. In extreme cases - low height above the bottom, very low velocity and high 'gravity' - you could still end up with the ball being embedded in the ground.

This makes your collision code a little harder, but at least you won't end up with balls flying out of the screen because of a buildup of acceleration errors.

Start with the code you have for acceleration and velocity, then if there's a collision you'll need to go back and do it again after figuring out how far into the path the collision occurred. You can start with simply using that as a ratio, but if you're aiming for real accuracy then you'll need to do some fun math to really make it work. There's some calculus involved to figure out the true velocity at impact and the effect of gravity after rebound, but it shouldn't be too hard to find references for all of this stuff.

The other thing you might want to do is add some reduction in the velocity after impact. Perfect elastic collisions give the same velocity after the collision, but in the real world some of the momentum of the object is wasted as heat, sound, etc. You can represent this by using a small multiplier to the reversed velocity - multiply by `0.99` or something - to add some loss into the collision.

Since you're almost never going to get a perfect balance in your errors, the ball is either going to speed up or slow down, eventually escaping or sitting on the floor. Make sure you have a strategy for dealing with both cases when they happen.

And when you get to collisions at arbitrary angles... the math gets more interesting again.

---

Oh, and don't forget to scale your acceleration values by the `gameTime`. The `ElapsedGameTime` property will tell you how long it was since `Update` was last called, and it's going to be inconsistent. If a frame takes a long time to process then the ball's acceleration will be slower. Likewise short frame times will make the ball move faster.